# Restriction of a metric terminology

Tags: metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $Y\subseteq X$, does one say $Y$ is a metric space when the metric on $X$, $d$, is restricted to $Y$ or does one say $Y$ is a metric space when $d$ is restricted to $Y\times Y$ since the domain of $d$ is technically the product $X \times X$?

Comment: I usually avoid the issue by saying that $Y$ is a metric space with the metric *induced by* $d$. Technically this is $d$ restricted to $Y\times Y$, but you’ll often see or hear the sloppier version.

Comment: A metric on $X$ is the function $d : X\times X \to \mathbb{R}_+$ such that... So I would say that the restriction of $d$ on $Y\times Y$ is a metric on $Y$ and call it the induced metric.

Comment: Thank you for your comments

Comment: I would just say "$Y$ is a metric subspace of $X$", or possibly "$Y$ is a sub metric space of $X$". Intuitively, these imply that the metric is involved in the subspace relatiionship, where the restriction of $d$ is the obvious meaning. Of course when introducing any new terminology, you should define it. But in this case, I consider the likelyhood of mis-understanding by someone who missed the definition to be very small.